# What happens when a Promise is returned from an async function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, async-await, aws-sdk

If a function returns a `Promise` *and* is marked as `async`, is it returning `Promise<Promise<DoWorkResponse>>`?

`tslint` tells me that I should keep the function marked as async. I am concerned that I am somehow doubly wrapping the promise that the `Lambda` client returns.

```
const doWork = async (event: MyEvent): Promise<DoWorkResponse> => {
  return new Lambda({ region: process.env.region })
    .invoke({
      FunctionName: process.env.doWorkLambdaName,
      InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
      LogType: 'Tail',
      Payload: JSON.stringify(event),
    })
    .promise()
    .then((response: Lambda.InvocationResponse) => {
      if (response.StatusCode !== 200) {
        const errorMessage = `Error occurred invoking DoWork Lambda. ${response}`;
        console.error(errorMessage);
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
      }
      return JSON.parse(response.Payload as string);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it returning `Promise<Promise<DoWorkResponse>>`?

No, a Promise will never resolve to a promise. If it gets `resolve()`d with a promise, the Promise will resolve to the promises value, the same happens when returning from an async function. However you could actually use `await` here to flatten your code a bit:

```
 async function doWork (event: MyEvent): Promise<DoWorkResponse> {
   const response = await new Lambda({ region: process.env.region })
    .invoke({
      FunctionName: process.env.doWorkLambdaName,
      InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
      LogType: 'Tail',
      Payload: JSON.stringify(event),
    })
    .promise();

   if (response.StatusCode !== 200) {
     const errorMessage = `Error occurred invoking DoWork Lambda. ${response}`;
     console.error(errorMessage);
     throw new Error(errorMessage);
   }

   return JSON.parse(response.Payload as string);    
}
```

Comment: This flattened code is precisely what I was thinking about. Actually, I was going to use [await-to-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-to-js) to make it even simpler.
   `const [error, response] = await to(new Lambda({ region: process.env.region }))...  if(error || response.statusCode !== 200) { // Handle error }`

Answer (score 3):

It’s ok, actually Async functions convert the return value to a promise if the reruned value is not already a promise. And if it’s already a promise it will be returned without change

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was hoping.